# Bisymmetric covariance matrix in Auto-Regressive Model

Tags: r, covariance-matrix, autoregressive, symmetry

When I learning Time Series, about the Auto-Regressive model (AR) of order $p$:
$$x_t=\alpha_1x_{t-1}+\dots+\alpha_px_{t-p}+w_t,$$
where $w_t$ is a time series of white noises. The textbook (Paul & Andrew, Introductory Time series with R) introduce an R code for fitting an AR model to a historical time series.

By using a Global Temperature time series data from the book, (I think it is not necessary to give the data) it tells us to fit the AR model using the code `ar(x)`. So, I first put the time series data into `Global.ts`, then let `Global.ar <- ar(Global.ts)` to store the AR model.

By typing `Global.ar$order` it outputs `4`, which means this is an $AR(4)$ model. Now I want to calculate the confidence interval of these four coefficients, hence I typed `Global.ar$asy.var` to observe the $4\times 4$ covariance matrix.
[image: Covariance matrix]

It is reasonable to observe this matrix is symmetric because the function $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ is symmetric, but one can also easily observe it is bisymmetric (symmetric along both diagonals). Why is it bisymmetric? In particular, why is it true that the matrix will be symmetric along the other diagonal? These numbers are bisymmetric without decimal error, so I don't think it is a coincidence.

What I thought is weird because, if it is bisymmetric, then the variance of $\alpha_1$ will be the same as the variance of $\alpha_4$, similarly variances of $\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ must be the same, but normally one would expect the variances of four coefficients $\alpha_i$ are different.

I've tried to prove this myself, but it is hard to get to know what is inside the implementation of the `ar()` function in R. Any help?

Comment: If anyone want to take a look at the Global Temperature data used in here. Starts from January 1856 to December 2005, each month is recorded. http://mathb.in/54616